# Complex(?) regex for filling the "title" attribute of <a> tag in massive list of links

Tags: html, regex, text, visual-studio-code

I have a series of `<ol>` elements on a page. Each of their `<li>`s contain text followed by a source for the text, which is a hyperlink.

Here's an example:

```
<ol>
<li>One plus one equals two (<a href="https://me.com" target="_blank">Me</a>)</li>
<li>Your &quot;reality&quot;, sir, is lies and balderdash, and I'm delighted to say that I have no grasp of it whatsoever (<a href="https://bvm.com" target="_blank">Baron von Munchausen</a>)</li>
</ol>
```

I would like to make each a href tag have a `title` attribute which is the entirety of the text before the bracketed source. So the above example would become:

```
<ol>
<li>One plus one equals two (<a title="One plus one equals two" href="https://me.com" target="_blank">Me</a>)</li>
<li>Your &quot;reality&quot;, sir, is lies and balderdash, and I'm delighted to say that I have no grasp of it whatsoever (<a title="Your &quot;reality&quot;, sir, is lies and balderdash, and I'm delighted to say that I have no grasp of it whatsoever" href="https://bvm.com" target="_blank">Baron von Munchausen</a>)</li>
</ol>
```

What's the best regex to use to achieve this, if this is even doable with a find/replace regex? – I'm using VSCode if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

```
<li>(.*) \(<a href
```

to

```
<li>$1 (<a title="$1" href
```

Result

```
<ol>
  <li>One plus one equals two (<a title="One plus one equals two" href="https://me.com" target="_blank">Me</a>)</li>
  <li>Your &quot;reality&quot;, sir, is lies and balderdash, and I'm delighted to say that I have no grasp of it whatsoever (<a title="Your &quot;reality&quot;, sir, is lies and balderdash, and I'm delighted to say that I have no grasp of it whatsoever" href="https://bvm.com" target="_blank">Baron von Munchausen</a>)</li>
</ol>
```

You will have to vet it for double quotes